# Can I set a cookie after a submit button in a form has been pressed?

Tags: php, forms, cookies, setcookie

I have a simple html form and want to set a cookie value to 1, for example, if the submit button was pressed. How can I do it?

The form looks like that:

```
<form action="auth.php">
            <label for="fname">Enter your name: </label>
            <input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="John" required />
            <br />
            <br />
            <label for="fsurname">Enter your surname:</label>
            <input type="text" id="fsurname" placeholder="Doe" required />
            <br />
            <br />
            <label for="email">Enter your email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="stupidlady123@yandex.ru" required>
            <br />
            <br />      
            <input type="submit" value="Register!"  />
            <!-- <?php 
                setcookie('Form', '1'); 
                echo $_COOKIE['Form'];
            ?> -->
        </form>
```

I've tried setting cookie in an action file (auth.php) and after submit button. But, as I understand, once data is sent to the server, I cant set the cookie any longer.

Comment: _"But, as I understand, once data is sent to the server, I cant set the cookie any longer."_ - That shouldn't be an issue as long as you set it before any output (just like any header). There's also the caveat that `$_COOKIE` won't be populated/set with the new cookie until the next page request. The manual explains all this, and more: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: I do understand that, but I need to set the cookie after the output, not before. So basically the cookie marks that the form was filled, so after clicking the submit button, the value should be set.

Comment: But can you use a SESSION variable in auth.php when receive a GET value?

Comment: _"I do understand that, but I need to set the cookie after the output,"_ - Then you either should set it in your `auth.php` (which should work) or set it using JS when the user submits the form (but before the form is sent to `auth.php`). Then you would need to add an eventlistener that stops the form from submitting, setting the cookie and then submit the form. Remember that PHP is _server side_, which means that it will be executed before the client (browser) even gets and shows the page. So PHP won't know if the user submitted the form or not, until it gets a request to `auth.php`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to put your `setcookie` **before** any `html` tag as you can see in php doc : https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.setcookie.php ;

Secondly, your cookies can't be used because you're not setting him for every documents. You have to place `'/'` in your `setcookie` like :

```
<?php setcookie('form','1',time()+60*60*24*30,'/'); ?>
```

You can use instead `$_SESSION` which is more modulable.